# unterminated string literal issue

Tags: php, javascript

First timer here, and total noob when it comes to PHP and JavaScript.

I have 2 lines of code which are identical, however one works and one kicks out a unterminated string literal error.

One that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('vehiclemake').value
                                         = "<?php echo $_POST['vehiclemake'];?>";
</script>
```

One that doesn't:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('PostcodeSelect').value =
                                        "<?php echo $_POST['PostcodeSelect'];?>";
</script>
```

The only thing I can think of is that the postcode select POST variable has an underscore in it eg: AB1_1BA does this need escaping or something?

Any help greatly appreciated, cheers!

Comment: my bet is the POST variable contains a line break. Look at the generated HTML code to find out what the problem is

Comment: @Chris can you post the HTML rendered version of both the scripts by viewing the source? If `$_POST` variable has `chr(10)`, it might be an issue too. So use `trim()` on the `$_POST['PostcodeSelect']`.

Comment: I'd make sure to use <script type="text/javascript">
as opposed to <script> as well.

Comment: <script> is valid (at least in html5). Look at the generated html code to see what's breaking the script (might be the $_POST isn't set and it echoes a php error?)

Comment: @dibs: That's *only* true if you use one of the older doctypes, with the current html doctype this is *not* necessary.

Comment: Could you also share the html of the page? Because you are saying that you are new to javascript as well, possibly meaning it's not necessarily a php error as everybody seems to be assuming (e.g. are both vehiclemake and PostcodeSelect, <select> elements?).

Comment: @DavidMulder, Unterminated string literal comes only when the line is not terminated. So, there must be a new line character as Damien said.

Comment: Argh, wanting to downvote my own answer currently *facepalm*, wasn't reading well enough and stopped reading at "one works and..." assuming it was mentioning that the other did not. (As normally errors get quite a focused position in questions) Oh well, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `json_encode()`:

```
document.getElementById('vehiclemake').value = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['vehiclemake']);?>;
```

It will take care to properly quote all special characters in your string.

Comment: The html code it generates is :

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('vehiclemake').value = "AC";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('PostcodeSelect').value="
B11_4";
</script> 

causing the line break somehow? but I don't understand/know enough to stop that doing it. trim() also didn't work.

Comment: ack don't know how to display code properly in the comments - basically the linebreak appears straight after <script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('PostcodeSelect').value="

Comment: usuing json encode I get : document.getElementById('PostcodeSelect').value=""\r\nB11_4"";

Comment: which is all on 1 line, but still doesn't display, do I need to escape out of those invisible chars or sometihng?

Comment: As @Pekka suggested, you have a newline in your POST data. With `json_encode()` you get it encoded properly in the string.

Comment: Judging by the doubled quotes in what you posted, you haven't removed the quotes around `<?php echo ... ?>`. You _don't_ need the quotes when you use `json_encode()`, they will be added automatically.

Comment: okay cool, so how can I avoid that?  reformat the Database where I'm grabbing the variable from or can I escape the new line in that command?  Sorry, as I said I'm a total noob!

Comment: Look at what I have posted in my answer and compare it _carefully_ with what you are trying.

Comment: removed the double quotes and no longer get an error, but it still doesn't display in the selectbox.  Confusing stuff!

Comment: Try to track where you're getting the newline in the value from. Also try `<?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['PostcodeSelect'])) ?>`

Comment: I get no notifications or anything in firebug anymore, it just doesn't work. I'm assuming the linebreak is at the very start of the variable.just don't know enough to know how to remove it. Thanks for all the help so far thought guys!

Comment: it's all definitely on 1 line now though, so thankyou for that!

Comment: okay it works now if I go into the MYSQL database and overwrite a field, then choose that option.  However there's 700 rows for me to amend, what could be causing the imported fields not to work but the ones that are just typed in to work okay?  Is this because I'm deleting the linebreak char at source?

Answer (score 0):

For your stuff, If `$_POST` variable has `chr(10)`, it might be an issue too. So use `trim()` on the `$_POST['PostcodeSelect']`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('PostcodeSelect').value="<?php echo trim($_POST['PostcodeSelect']); ?>";
</script>
```

Might work! Best guess!